# Rails models association not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, migration, model-associations

thanks for this commmunity, it has helped me alot already. This is the first question I have to post myself, and it is somewhat specific to my project.

I have started from MHartls great rails tutorial.
There were models for Users and Microposts and I have added a Cars model, where each user can have a car (referenced by the car_id).

In the console I can create a user and a micropost, and assign the user to the micropost by stating post.user = michael and then it would set the post's user_id to michaels id.
I am trying to do the same for cars, where i can set a users car_id by stating michael.car = somecar but it gives an error even though the model associations LOOK exactly the same, and I have even remigrated the car_id to the user model as reference. See below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :cars

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :car

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :microposts
```

Here is my last migration for the car_id:

```
class Addreferencecartousers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    add_reference :users, :car 
    add_foreign_key :users, :cars
 end
end
```

in synch with what I had done for the user/micropost connection.

I am kind of lost on where else to look for why this does not work, does anyone have any hints/pointers on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your problem, the `belongs_to :cars` in the `User` model should be `belongs_to :car`, but in a reality I believe it will be more sense to call it as `has_many :cars` rather than a `belongs_to :car` because ***a user can have many cars*** and ***a car belongs to user***

Comment: Thanks, the devil is in the detail. The cardinality is correct for my needs though :)